# Is Theodore Roosevelt's writing ungrammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, books

Here is an excerpt from chapter 8 of [*Theodore Rex* by Edmund Morris](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/40923.Theodore_Rex). Morris quotes some of Roosevelt's writing and calls it ungrammatical. Can you explain what is ungrammatical about the passage?

> Musing on the behavior of screech owls, he produced one extraordinary, if ungrammatical, image:
>
> > They come up to the house after dark, and are fond of sitting in the elk-antlers over the gable. When the moon is up, by changing one's position, the little owl appears in sharp outline against the bright disk, seated on his many-tined perch

Comment: [Dangling modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier). Which, as the Wikipedia article is quick to point out, is only considered ungrammatical "in prescriptivist accounts of English".

Comment: Who said _they_ could decide where the borderline is?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, there is nothing ungrammatical. I think he is trying to pretend that _by changing one's position_ has an implied subject of _the little owl_, and that it "means" something different from what it actually means. This is nonsense, and has always been nonsense, no matter how many pedagogues have insisted on it: it is neither ungrammatical, nor does it mean something different from what the authors intended. It is only people who insist that language should be able to be solved like a mathematical equation who believe otherwise.

Comment: It is also 'ungrammatical' if the reader is left uncertain as to the exact meaning, as I am in this case.

Comment: @ColinFine, I’m not quite sure I follow your outright dismissal of dangling modifiers as grammatically dubitable. I for one tend to find them confusing and muddling, which is, really, the crux of why prescriptivists tend to outlaw them as ‘ungrammatical’ (unlike certain other ‘traditional rules’, this one is not based on something extraneous to the English language). I have yet to see a dangling modifier that did not add an element of confusion that would be dispensed with if the sentence were recast and the modifier undangled.

Comment: "The hanging [dangling] participle is **generally** condemned as ungrammatical, rather than as a mere error of style. But it has long been widely used, most famously by Shakespeare in Hamlet." (Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar, 1994)[bolding mine] If this is true, descriptivists should go with the flow and concede that the dangling modifier is ungrammatical.

Comment: It seems to me that the expression *"by changing one's position"* is probably referring to the reader/person. That if a person there at the scene was to change their position, then that person would be able to see the little owl better (owl silhouette against the bright moon).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: dangling modifiers are sometimes ambiguous. So sometimes are expressions which nobody condemns as ungrammatical. In many cases, (as here) there is formal ambiguity, but it is simply perverse to misunderstand it: once more, prescriptivists love to pretend that pragmatics is not part of language.

Comment: @Colin: True, ambiguity can always be created. The difference is that dangling modifiers do so almost by definition. I did not _misunderstand_ the cited quote here, but despite being quite firmly prescriptivist, the dangling modifier did make me pause and have to backtrack a few words to get back on track. [See what I did there?]

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: There is indeed some variation in where people draw the line of grammaticality. I am not impressed by "generally condemned as ungrammatical": to me, if it is widely used, it is _ipso facto_ grammatical, at least in some registers. But in any case I find the logic of "this has a reading in which phrase A refers to argument B, but was intended to mean that it refers to argument C, therefore it is ungrammatical" to be barely coherent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the comments on your question, one could conclude that the word *ungrammatical* has a rather technical meaning. Perhaps it would be useful to ponder whether Roosevelt's statement is as clear as it could be, or could be improved. Consider the potentially confusing part of his statement: "by changing one's position, the little owl appears..." Although the reader can probably guess at what Roosevelt means, this kind of construct can be confusing in other contexts. For example, "by pulling out one's hairs, the little owl builds a nest." Interpreted in the same way that we interpreted Roosevelt's statement, this could, at least at first glance, suggest that a person pulling out his own hair can have some effect on the owl's nest-building endeavors.

Perhaps the question of whether the statement qualifies as *ungrammatical* is not as important as the question of whether the statement is as clear as it could be.

Comment: One might also ask whether the text would lose some of its more "poetic" overtones if it were to be expressed more conventionally. It's not part of a technical manual, nor is it text that needs to be understood by illiterates (or dumb software). Reducing already trivial reader effort is not a relevant aspiration for such prose.